# From Twitter: When did Islamic literacy fall behind?

Tags: middle-ages, technology, middle-east, north-africa

This morning I found [this interesting question](https://twitter.com/iyad_elbaghdadi/status/953578226206564352) from verified Twitter user Iyad el-Baghdadi.

[image]

Transcription:

> Question to experts (and good researchers). My impression is that
>   parts of the classical Islamic world were highly literate (by the
>   standards of their time): When did the Islamic world start to fall way
>   behind in literacy rates, and why?
>
> Note of course that I'm talking about literacy rates in the context of
>   their own time, not in absolute terms. So "high/low" = within the
>   context of their own time.

Comment: Mongol invasions, Reconquista...

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/41304/at-what-point-did-europe-overtake-the-arabic-world-and-india-in-math-and-science/41314#41314

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy - Agree. Sadly, that question was closed.

Comment: @T.E.D.: That, and dogpiled with downvotes. It's unfortunate IMO because it was a good question. At any rate, I'd wager a drop of literacy might correlate with the Muslim change of attitude towards science.

Comment: The bulk of any difference would've came from the expansion of literacy in Europe beyond ecclesiastical and scribal circles, especially to the emerging urban middle class. Islamic literacy didn't necessarily drop in absolute terms, it just didn't expand the way Europe's dead. Which is also why I think Chinese literacy rates were higher than both.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy - I would too. However, literacy has one advantage over "math and science" in that it is (theoretically) objectively measurable.

Comment: @T.E.D. - Without further qualification, this question will not get a reasonable answer imho. A quick look at Wiki on *Literacy* will show just how complicated this topic can be. An **example**:"_... Cross-national comparisons of literacy rates are imperfect, given that different countries define literacy in different ways_". Even more difficult for a group of people, not by national boundaries, but personal belief.

Comment: @JAsia - That's one of the first things I noticed researching this. Perhaps its simpler in a culture where everyone's first language is Arabic, but in England for a while after the Norman conquest, there were three written languages in use, and people who could only read and write in English might be considered illiterate. (Whereas these days the term for that is "American". :-0  )

Comment: There's also the banning of [printing press in the Ottoman empire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_spread_of_the_printing_press#Ottoman_Empire), which its let Jews and Christians use the press but not Muslims.

Comment: @T.E.D. - I've found measuring literacy rates in an entity such as the Ottoman empire has been a bit of a crap shoot.  If I was a literate in the Arabic language, but not not the official Turkish language of the Ottoman empire...was I counted as illiterate or literate?

Comment: @Semaphore - The drastic drop in educational facilities between the Sultanate of Rum and the Ottoman empire would lead me to believe there was an actual drop in literacy and not just a lack of expansion after the Mongol invasion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One cannot be literate without books to read, and regardless on one's religious beliefs The Bible is one of the great works of literature of Western civilization. The invention of the printing press by Gutenberg, accompanied by the widespread printing of The Bible in the vulgar tongues of Europe, [would put copies of The Bible in most [Northern] European middle class homes within a century](http://eduscapes.com/bookhistory/commodity/2.htm). By 1610 [German publishers are printing](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:1500-1700_English_and_German_book_markets_compared.png) roughly 28,000 distinct titles per decade; English printers would start to catch up about thirty years later.

Contrariwise, the Ottoman Empire [forbid the use of printing presses by Muslims](https://sureshemre.wordpress.com/2014/01/18/on-the-late-adoption-of-the-printing-press-in-the-ottoman-empire/) in its domain until the 18 century, roughly 300 years after Gutenberg.

Comment: Still, up **until** the printing press, you'd think the Islamic world's situation with the Koran would be roughly equivalent to the Christian world's situation with The Bible. Probably better, as even a lot of illiterate Muslims knew Arabic, whereas few Christians knew Latin, Greek, or Aramaic.

Comment: The decline in Islamic literacy rates was well before the printing press invention.  You may have answered 'why it took so long to catch up' but failed to answer "When did the Islamic world start to fall way behind in literacy rates, and why?" completely.

Comment: Literacy = Printing press? Too monolithic and clearly an Orientalist narrative 
because 1) Since when did Ottoman become the representative nation of Islam? It may be from a Western perspective. 2) Muslims exist in many parts of the world. Also, whilst we're looking at it from a _paper_ perspective, don't forget their 8th century paper mills (Baghdad).

Comment: @JAsia: What has the production of paper in 8th century Baghdad got to do with when Islam fell behind Western Europe in literacy? The two occur many centuries apart by any measure.

Comment: @JAsia: to read you need books. If you have printing press, books are *a lot* cheaper and less error prone than if they are copied by a scribe. If you don't believe this, try printing a 300-page pdf vs writing it down by hand :) Plus, TED's graph in the other answer shows that the spread of printing press is really correlated with when literacy in the Christian world took off.

Comment: But, good point about discussing only the Ottomans. The Ottomans did control most of the traditional Islamic intellectual centres (Egypt, Syria, Iraq, ...), but at the same time there was also Safavid Persia, Morocco, and the Mughal Empire in India. Curious about the reception of printing press there, especially in Persia because it is one of the traditional intellectual centres.

Comment: Isn't this a bit chicken-and-egg, though?  If you don't have a significant number of literate people who can also afford to buy books, there is not much point to printing them in volume.  So there must have been a base of literate people pre-printing.

Comment: @jamesqf there's always a base of literate people. Printing press reduces the barrier to enter that club.

Comment: A detail, but "The invention of the printing press by Gutenberg [,,,] would put copies of The Bible in most European middle class homes within a century" might be true in the Protestant world, certainly not in the Catholic domain. Even in the nineteenth century in France, the Catholic church and Catholic organizations were strongly battling against the dissemination of Bibles organized by Protestants, up to organizing burning of Bibles.

Comment: @Joel: Yes, thank you - corrected in question to "Northern European".

Comment: Coming back to this more than a year later, it sure looks like the content of my answer (and graph) is actually *backing up* this answer. I still think the last paragraph is more of an effect of the problem rather than a cause. The problem itself happened around 1550, but that timing is totally consistent with the cause being the printing press.

Answer (score 3):

From what I've been able to dig up, it was about 1550.

Its tough to find good numbers on literacy going back that far. I found one set of numbers used in a couple of places that trace back to a paper from Eltjo Buringh and Jan Luiten van Zanden titled [Charting the "Rise of the West"](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.553.9220&rep=rep1&type=pdf), but sadly their methods only allowed for producing numbers in Medieval Christendom. Basically, they estimate it based on the production of manuscripts and some judicious application of economics and statistics.

The interesting thing though I think is the variance. They found a range of about 1-20% literacy, in general very slowly increasing, up until roughly the popularization of Printing Press (1550ish, to be specific). After that literacy shot up (although still at different rates in different countries, which they dive into in detail).

[image]

The authors use their same techniques to try to estimate literacy in China and India *after* they got printing presses. However they explicitly state they couldn't really do that in the Islamic World specifically due to the Ottomans outlawing printing (or even the possession of printed material!). If they *could* get you numbers, it seems likely they would be in the same general ballpark as they were during the manuscript era (which they were effectively still in).

So based on the this paper, and the methods they used, it is pretty much idiomatic that the Ottoman prohibition of printing is where the Islamic World's literacy rate started to get left in the dust.

Comment: small note: It appears the Ottomans did not outlaw printing press outright. The ban only applied to Muslims, and [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_spread_of_the_printing_press#Ottoman_Empire), Christians & Jews in the empire had printing press within the century of Gutenberg's invention

Answer (score 0):

The key reason is the Ottoman empire and it's policies.

Prior to the Ottoman empire, the Suljuk Sultanate (Sultanate of Rum) put tremendous stress on education.  The Ince Minare Madrasa (source at bottom) was one of 24 Colleges built in the Sultanate of Rums capital of Konya and well over 50 of such structures were built Anatolia.  The Sultanate of Rum was directly responsible for the height of Islamic literacy and their literacy rates far exceeding medieval Europe and quite likely even the Chinese.

However the Sultanate of Rum collapsed in the face of the Mongol invasion, becoming vassals of the Mongol empire.  From these ashes rose the Ottoman empire who put almost the exact opposite stress on literacy and education.

There are a few reasons here:

1) The Supression of the Oghuz.  Early Ottoman history is a long and violent struggle with the Oghuz tribes.  To keep them subdued, education and literacy was withheld (and likely part of the reason of the ban of the printing press).

2) Nature of the Ottoman empire.  The empire was somewhat a conglomeration of a variety of peoples and languages...Greek, Lydian, Phrygian, Cilician all fit into this empire (IE you could be a subject of this empire without really speaking the tongue of the empire).  Many of these peoples were nomadic and education/literacy was an expensive prospect for little gain.  I have seen the proposal floated that the Ottoman empire was actually more literate than given credit for, but these people were literate in their mother tongue and not the Turkish language.

3) Scripting (though this point is somewhat debated) wasn't easy.  To make proper use of 'Ottomanish/Turkish' script, one needed to learn 2 languages to really be effective (correction in progress).  The Elite would learn both Arabic and Persian, allowing them to effectively make use of their scripting, however most subjects of the Ottoman empire would only speak their mother tongue.

Edit from comments:
sourcing on that can be found here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ottoman_Turkish_language "It borrows, in all aspects, extensively from Arabic and Persian, and it was written in the Ottoman Turkish alphabet. During the peak of Ottoman power, Persian and Arabic vocabulary accounted for up to 88% of its vocabulary,[3] while words of Arabic origins heavily outnumbered native Turkish words". Apparently if you didn't speak Arabic and Persian, the Turkish written language was pretty much unintelligible and a good segment of the Ottoman empire used kaba Türkçe ("raw/vulgar Turkish")

4) No specific mission to educate youth.  Somewhere in Christian Europe, the mandate to educate youth came about.  Mosques and Imam's had no such explicit mission to educate youth in this manner.  As an odd side note, education was usually around the Quoran (believed to hold the key to all knowledge, not simply Theological), which was written in Arabic and does not help that much with Turkish literacy.

5) No stress on Education by the Ottoman empire. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%9Eevket_S%C3%BCreyya_Aydemir wrote in a few of his books that educational facilities in the Ottoman empire were exceedingly rare.  Erdine (a major city close to Istanbul) only had one middle school and one high school to serve the entire city, and this wasn't uncommon throughout the empire.

By the time the Ottoman empire began to address this lack of education, it was already the 18th century and the majority of the world had long surpassed the Islamic world.

Madrasa information from Google books: (https://books.google.ca/books?id=qGb4pyoseH4C&pg=PT363&lpg=PT363&dq=sultanate+of+rum+literacy&source=bl&ots=Uf7p9JhSZR&sig=p_r7Ocu-dqGZkR1H2u06pVlEhY4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjWqqLSx9_YAhVNaq0KHdz_CmAQ6AEIUTAK#v=onepage&q=sultanate%20of%20rum%20literacy&f=false)

Comment: I take issues with point (4), as Jewish literacy in the Middle and Dark Ages revolved around study of the Torah, and was consistently very high right up to the modern day.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens - your issue with point 4 confuses me.  I am simply pointing out that early Christianity (Charlemagne leading the way) mandated the constructions of schools and churches so that "the bright young boys of the realm could read and write" and launched legislation encouraging monks and clergy to "teach children who were not members of their religious community", which heavily helped early Christian Europes literacy rates.   The Islamic world and Imams never promoted this.  I fail to see your objection

Comment: Source for previous comment.  https://books.google.ca/books?id=6feKDfRM9sYC&pg=PA240&lpg=PA240&dq=medieval+christian+mandate+to+teach+children&source=bl&ots=ihCnuV0m_Y&sig=ws03UiZqK6vEnUUGS_WQdkW9lDM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiUq57T0d_YAhVLR6wKHWQ_CFwQ6AEIMjAC#v=onepage&q=medieval%20christian%20mandate%20to%20teach%20children&f=false

Comment: The side-note about the Quran is contra-evidenced by the Jewish experience.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens - A person that could read the Torah was considered literate, while a person who could read the Quoran (Arabic) but couldn't read Turkish was considered Illiterate in the Ottoman empire as they couldnt read/write Turkish.  Point ties into point 2 "I have seen the proposal floated that the Ottoman empire was actually more literate than given credit for, but these people were literate in their mother tongue and not the Turkish language."

Comment: Well, yeah! Books could only be printed in the Ottoman Empire by non-Muslims, for non-Muslims, only in tongues other than Turkish and Arabic, until the 18th century. How could one learn to read and write Turkish when a hand-copied book cost nearly as much as a new car today. (One year's wages for a labourer or craftsman)

Comment: @PieterGeerkens - Decline in Islamic literacy was as early as 13th century, printing press was 15th century.  Printing press ban had nothing to do with the decline.  We could also attribute the lack of 18th century literacy with the lack of computing technology using your logic.

Comment: 3's an interesting point. However, not only are Semitic and Indo-European unrelated and Persian and Altaic unrelated, but Persian **is** Indo-European.

Comment: @T.E.D. - sourcing on that can be found here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ottoman_Turkish_language   " It borrows, in all aspects, extensively from Arabic and Persian, and it was written in the Ottoman Turkish alphabet. During the peak of Ottoman power, Persian and Arabic vocabulary accounted for up to 88% of its vocabulary,[3] while words of Arabic origins heavily outnumbered native Turkish words".  Apparently if you didn't speak Arabic and Persian, the Turkish written language was pretty much unintelligible and a good segment of the Ottoman empire used kaba Türkçe ("raw/vulgar Turkish")

Answer (score -1):

The key words in the question are "by the standard of the time". Indeed during the early middle age Islamic society was more literate than Western European one. Since then the literacy rates did not decline anywhere. They simply grew in the West at faster rate. It is the "standard of the time" which changed. And it changed in the West faster than it did in the Islamic countries. And the reason of this is book printing. And the wise spread of books was possible because the society was more secular.

Comment: This answer lacks references, dates, and explanations beside "book printing" already pointed out in other answers.